# Can you marry Serana in Skyrim: Dawnguard?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

In Skyrim, I want to marry Serana, the follower you get from the Dawnguard quest series.

Is it possible, if not, will it ever be?

Comment: Hrm.  I wonder if we should pop a more general question:  "Do any of the Skyrim DLC include eligible bachelors/bachelorettes?"

Comment: "There's a mod for that..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of right now, it is not possible to marry Serana. See the link to the Elder Scrolls Wiki as well as discussion forum posts [here](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/57953/t1742680-marrying-serana/) and [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/63227648) on this very topic.

> Serana will politely refuse a proposal of marriage, mentioning her unease with temples and complicated history.

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Serana#Trivia

As to will it ever be possible, anything is possible. You are certainly not the only person who has suggested this, and it is not unreasonable that this option could be patched into the game in the future. There is even a petition [here](http://www.change.org/petitions/bethesda-softworks-allow-serana-to-be-married) to encourage Bethesda to add this option. As of right now though, there are no plans to make marriage an option.

Comment: Okay, so Serena is afraid of temples eh? Even if the vampirism is cured? I heard there's a mod that allows Serena to be married.